Set specific "Brands" attribute term programatically to a product in WooCommerce
I want to check for example Brand "Apple" Exist as a term in Brands Attribute, then setup the brand apple to this product as taxonomy type.
$product_id = 214246; 
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// check if the product exist 
if ($product) {  
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if (!empty($attributes)) {
        // Loop through each attribute
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            // Get the attribute label
            $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label($attribute->get_name());

            // Get the attribute value
            $attribute_value = '';

            // Check if the attribute is a taxonomy type
            if ($attribute->is_taxonomy()) {
                $attribute_value = implode(', ', wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(), $attribute->get_name(), array('fields' => 'names')));
            } 

            // Display the attribute label and value
            echo '<p><strong>' . $attribute_label . ':</strong> ' . $attribute_value . '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        
        // I want to add if the brands Apple exist if not then add apple as a brand then set this brand to this product.
   
    }
}

The Brand is a global product attribute:


How have you add the Brand product attribute taxonomy in WooCommerce, can you show a screenshot of the related settings, or are you using a 3rd party plugin for that? Your question is unclear actually and you should better explain things and context.

@LoicTheAztec No i am not using 3rd party plugin, see the screenshot in the link below: https://prnt.sc/gKwbbjoKD6J2,
I want to assign brand Apple to this product ID: 214246

On my side, my answer code was working just fine with your global attribute "Brands" settings. So I don't know why it's not working in your case.
